# User Pinned Files - MS Graph EndPoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to pin a file or get user pinned files. I am searching through MS Graph API, but could not find any info.
Is there any other API to get user pinned files and pin a file. pinned files appear in client office applications.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available from the Microsoft Graph API.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.